# C#: Can't manually change string value in VS debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a breakpoint set in a method that receives a string parameter. I'm trying to change the value of that parameter, by editing it in the Locals window (or the mouseover popup), but it immediately snaps back to the original value.

Could this be a configuration or code pattern issue? I'm certain I've changed string values in this way before.

Comment: Did you use quotes (`"string"`) around the string in the edit window, if not it won't work?

Comment: I did use quotes.

Comment: @Kristaps Baumanis, What about this issue now? Would you please share the latest information here?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I think the problem was that I was debugging a release build, but I'm not sure. I tried to reproduce it just now and this time I got an error message "This value cannot be written to the process being debugged", which wasn't the case before. In debug build I can change values with no problem.

Comment: @Kristaps Baumanis, I got the same issue, you are correct, we just could edit it in debug mode, we couldn't change the value in release mode.

Answer (score -4):

I test a simple sample in my VS2017 Enterprise version with debug target, it works well after the Breakpoint was hit.

[image]

(1)Not very sure that which VS version you use, but as you said that it worked well before, please make sure that your VS was the latest version(installed the latest update package).

(2) If your VS installed any extension tools or add-ins, you could remove or disable them firstly, and then check the result, or you could run your VS in safe mode.

devenv.exe/safemode

(3) Please also reset your VS settings, and then create a new simple app, view the result like mine.

TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings.

**Update:**

It really has this issue in release mode, but it has no this issue in debug mode, so my understanding is that just use the default debug mode would resolve this issue.

Comment: I don't really get this gif. You change the value to what it was before, so you have no way of knowing whether the change actually worked.